# I want to update a list that I'm using in a while loop, while the loop is still running. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: python

I have a function that uses a while loop, which I ideally want to set up and then run in the background. In this while loop, I use a list. What I want to do is if I think of something else to put in this list, I can simply edit the list, and then the next time the loop begins the updated list is used. At the moment, I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I tried to define the list in a separate programme, and then import it at the start of each loop. I have then updated the list in the separate programme, but this hasn't been reflected in the output.

```
import time
while True:
    from list_test import sample_list
    print(sample_list)
    time.sleep(30)
```

When I update sample_list, the output doesn't change. Does anyone know why this is? Apologies if the solution is simple, I'm quite new to programming in general!

Comment: Updating the list in another program won't work. They all have their own version of it. If you want to share data between Python runtime instances, better use a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments it generally not adviced to update a list you are iterating over (even though you are just printing it in your example). That said you could use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) with the [reload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) method. For example like this:

```
import time
import importlib

list_module = importlib.import_module("list_test")
sample_list = list_module.sample_list
while True:
    sample_list = importlib.reload(list_module).sample_list
    print(sample_list)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Note that you have to update the list by hand to see the changes. Updating the list with another program at runtime will not work.

Comment: But this will only update the list if the list has been edited in the other file and that file is then saved, right? It will not update the list to any changed made at runtime in another instance that is using the list.

Comment: I updated my answer for your comment, after doing some tests.

Comment: I can not reproduce this. I have one module defining a list and adding elements to that list in a loop in `main`. I run this program, and while it runs, start an interactive shell with your code. But the list I get from `importlib` is always just the initial list, without added elements. Can you provide a full example, or are we talking about different things here?

Comment: Added a full example.

Comment: Nope. What you see when you run `import_test` is just the output of `list_test`. Remember that when you import a module, that module is executed, and `list_test` never terminates. To see, you can either add something to differentiate between the `print` from the two modules, or put the loop code in `list_test` in `if __name__ == `__main__` so it is not executed when importing the module.

Comment: Oooohhh... I totally forgot about that. Thanks for the hint! I will update my answer again to remove that falsy information.